# ConstraintLayout Vs RelativeLayout & CardView - Cache and Memory space

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-relativelayout

I have developed an application that retrieves data from **json** to local database on mobile and displays it from local database with `RecyclerView`, and my container layout is like below :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:id="@+id/detailContainerLayout"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_bottom"
    >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/article_title"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:layout_width="220dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:textColor="@color/buttons_background"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_main"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_date"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="9dp"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:textSize="@dimen/date_size"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_place"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1.1"

            android:maxLines="1"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_placeIcon"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/article_subtitle"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/textColor"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
        android:gravity="start|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1.4"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_subtitleICON"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/textColor"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            android:gravity="start|bottom"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
            android:layout_marginRight="9dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="start|bottom"
        android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"

        >
        <elryad.harajsooq.ActionbarContent.AllAds.ui.DynamicHeightNetworkImageView
            android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/photo_placeholder"
            android:layout_gravity="start|bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
```

So when I used `CardView` or `RelativeLayout` as container for my items, they make my application cache and memory usage very high, my  **DATA** was 20MB and My **CACHE** was 50MB+, but after I changed container layout to ConstraintLayout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="@drawable/border_bottom">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/article_title"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/buttons_background"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_main"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/thumbLayout"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



   <items ....
           ....>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

the Data and cache went back to a normal state and small size as below:

[image]

I don't know what happened with CardView or RelativeLayout that makes my application data and cache use high space.... maybe someone can explain that.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a simple project demonstrating that behaviour?

Comment: @azizbekian ok, simply the application retrieve data from json to local database and then i display it from data base but i don't know why the cache and space effect from that.

Comment: Because cache has no any relatance with what layout do you use. It's interesting.

Comment: I think, the problem may lie in DynamicHeightNetworkImageView. Actually android system takes a lot of memory to show images as it has to convert images to bitmap. Please, use picasso or other libraries to test out this idea.

Answer (score 1):

Contraint Layout has

Left-to-right bug fix (layout params were cached, preventing you to change them at runtime)

Performance improvements on first layout

Ratio support was extended to work when both dimensions are set to MATCH_CONSTRAINT (0dp). This deal with the case when one dimension is constrained and you want to define the other dimension as a ratio.

So definitely you have these performance hikes in Constraint Layout so it's better to use it rather than Relative layout.

try to find out more [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 0):

> Try to clear your stored array and other that you use in views, also
>   clear variable and all that you initialized. Cause it might be take
>   space for that. Try to clear on backspace or else when you have no
>   use.

Answer (score 0):

Complex Layout, included nested `LinearLayout` will have more `Object` created during rendering. `ConstraintLayout` is a flat layout to reduce those overhead.